# Python Selenium Xpath from firebug not found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to login to the ESPN website using selenium.  Here is my code thus far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

url = "http://www.espn.com/fantasy/"
driver.get(url)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/section/section/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]")
login_button.click()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input")))
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Basically, there are 2 steps, first I have to click the login button and then I have to fill in the form.  Currently, I am clicking the login button and the form is popping up but then I can't find the form.  I have been using firebug to get the xpath as suggested in other SO questions.  I don't really know much about selenium so I am not sure where to look

Comment: The form pops up in an iframe. You need to switch to the iframe before you can reach the elements within it.

Comment: how did you know that for future problems, like what should I look for etc.

Comment: @qwertylpc, you should check whether there is an ancestor element with tag `<frame>` or `<iframe>`

Comment: Tricks of the trade. If you can't find an element and you know the path is valid, inspect the element (right click -> inspect), then trace the tree up from that element and see if <frame> shows up somewhere.

Comment: I would suggest that you not use XPaths that are that long and/or that begin at `html`. Those are going to be very brittle... very likely break if anything changes on the page. You are looking for an `A` tag that contains 'Log In' text... why not use `.find_element_by_link_text("Log In")`? After switching to the `iframe`, you can use `.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='email']")` to get your email `INPUT` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
driver.switch_to_frame('disneyid-iframe')
# handle authorization pop-up
driver.switch_to_default_content() # if required
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me, switching to the iframe first. Note that you will need to switch back out of the iframe after entering the credentials.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

url = "http://www.espn.com/fantasy/"
driver.get(url)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/section/section/div/section[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]")
login_button.click()

iframe = driver.find_element_by_id("disneyid-iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/div/label/span[2]/input")))
    element.send_keys("my username")

    import time
    time.sleep(100)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your answer is absolutely correct but if you're are able to give any answer, you have responsibility to provide optimised answer to OP as simple as possible instead of only manipulating mistakes of the OP. You can switch to frame by its id directly without finding that iframe element then switch, you can suggest to OP best locator to locate desire element using xpath or other instead of provided element positional locator which is not so much reliable. So I would suggest you always try to provide optimised answer. Thanks

Comment: @SaurabhGaur so... rather than ranting for a paragraph about how he needs to provide an "optimized answer" you could have just stated that he could just use `driver.switch_to.frame("disneyid-iframe")` as a one-liner to accomplish the frame switch.